# Hibernate criteria loads all the child data though our condition is not getting fulfilled

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have three entities :

---

```
 Organization
     - Id
     - visibilityFlag
     - List<BusinessGroup> tblmorgbusinessgroups

   BusinessGroup
     - Id
     - visibilityFlag
     - orgId
     - List<BusinessHierarchy> tblmorgbusinessgrouphies

   BusinessHierarchy
     - Id
     - visibilityFlag
     - bgId
```

Now I want to find out records where

```
org.id = "1"
org.visibilityFlag = "0"
bg.visibilityFlag = "0"
bh.visibilityFlag = "0"
```

---

I am creating crieteria on Organization so it is loading all the records of BusinessGroup and BusinessHierarchy if any of it's fulfils the above condition.

```
Criteria organizationDOCriteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(OrganizationDO.class);
organizationDOCriteria.createAlias("tblmorgbusinessgroups", "businessGroup");
organizationDOCriteria.createAlias("businessGroup.tblmorgbusinessgrouphies", "businessGroupHierarchy");
organizationDOCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organizationid", organizationId));
organizationDOCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("businessGroup.visibilityflag", visibilityFlag));
organizationDOCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("businessGroupHierarchy.visibilityflag", visibilityFlag));
organizationDOCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("visibilityflag", visibilityFlag));
Object organizationDOObj = organizationDOCriteria.uniqueResult();
```

I want to load the BusinessGroup/business hierarchy which has the visibilityFlag = "0";

---

```
-------------------------------------------------
Current Data
-------------------------------------------------
Orgid   visibilityFlag  Name
1       0               Org1

BusinessGroup
id  visibilityFlag  Name    orgId
1   0               Bg1     1
2   3               Bg2     1
3   0               Bg3     1

BusinessHierarchy
id  visibilityFlag  Name    bgId
1   0               BH1     1
2   0               BH2     2
3   0               BH3     1
4   3               BH4     1
5   0               BH5     3
6   0               BH6     3
7   0               BH7     2

-------------------------------------------------
Expected Output
-------------------------------------------------
Orgid   visibilityFlag  Name
1       0               Org1

BusinessGroup
id  visibilityFlag  Name    orgId
1   0               Bg1     1
3   0               Bg3     1

BusinessHierarchy
id  visibilityFlag  Name    bgId
1   0               BH1     1
3   0               BH3     1
5   0               BH5     3
6   0               BH6     3

-------------------------------------------------
Actual Output Data
-------------------------------------------------
Orgid   visibilityFlag  Name
1       0               Org1

BusinessGroup
id  visibilityFlag  Name    orgId
1   0               Bg1     1
2   3               Bg2     1
3   0               Bg3     1

BusinessHierarchy
id  visibilityFlag  Name    bgId
1   0               BH1     1
2   0               BH2     2
3   0               BH3     1
4   3               BH4     1
5   0               BH5     3
6   0               BH6     3
7   0               BH7     2
```

---

**Data object details**

**OrganizationDO**

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx.dataobject;

//Import statements

/**
 * The persistent class for the XXXTABLE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="XXXTABLE")
public class OrganizationDO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_XXXTABLE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_XXXTABLE",sequenceName="SEQ_XXXTABLE",allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1 )
    private Long organizationid;

    private String name;

    private String visibilityflag;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to OrgBusinessGroupDO
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tblmorganization", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OrgBusinessGroupDO> tblmorgbusinessgroups;

//Getter Setter methods
}
```

**BusinessGroupDO**

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx.dataobject;

//Import statements

/**
 * The persistent class for the XXXBUSGRPTABLE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="XXXBUSGRPTABLE")
public class OrgBusinessGroupDO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_XXXBUSGRPTABLE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_XXXBUSGRPTABLE",sequenceName="SEQ_XXXBUSGRPTABLE",allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1 )
    private Long businessgroupid;

    private String name;

    private String visibilityflag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORGANIZATIONID")
    private OrganizationDO tblmorganization;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to OrgBusinessGroupHierarchyDO
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tblmorgbusinessgroup")
    private List<OrgBusinessGroupHierarchyDO> tblmorgbusinessgrouphies;

    //Getters/setters and toString/hashcode
}
```

**BusinessGroupHierarchyDO**

```
package xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.dataobject;

//Import statements

/**
 * The persistent class for the XXXBUSINESSGRPHIETABLE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="XXXBUSINESSGRPHIETABLE")
public class OrgBusinessGroupHierarchyDO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_XXXBUSINESSGRPHIETABLE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_XXXBUSINESSGRPHIETABLE",sequenceName="SEQ_XXXBUSINESSGRPHIETABLE",allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1 )
    private Long hierarchyid;

    private String name;

    private String visibilityflag;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to OrgBusinessGroupDO
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BUSINESSGROUPID")
    private OrgBusinessGroupDO tblmorgbusinessgroup;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to OrgBusinessGroupHierarchyDO
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tblmorgbusinessgrouphie")
    private List<OrgBusinessGroupHierarchyDO> tblmorgbusinessgrouphies;
}
```

Comment: whats the db column type of visibilityFlag and what is the java type of value  you pass with visibilityFlag?

Comment: Its a varchar2(20) - db and String - java

Comment: all seems fine.. something may be wrong with mapping classes. Add them please and lets see whats up

Comment: @MaciejKowalski : Added the details as per your comment.

Comment: still seems fine.. have you tried with a HQL query equivalent? Just curious if you would still get all the Organization records that way

Comment: HQL won't work as I need to compare value of attribute of object and orgdo contains list of that object.